# Google maps API issue with geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I think I'm just doing something stupid because my javascript skills aren't the greatest. The following code produces a blank, gray map:

```
function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = "Minneapolis, MN";
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
           {
               lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
               lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
               addresslatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());  
           }
           else
           {
                   alert(status);
           }
        });
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: addresslatlng
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
      }
```

However, if simply change the "center: addresslatlng" to:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
```

It works fine.

I tried using **lat** and **lng** and that does NOT work either:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding is asynchronous.  You need to use the results inside the call back function:

```
function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = "Minneapolis, MN";
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
       {
           lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
           lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
           addresslatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());  
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: addresslatlng
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
       }
       else
       {
               alert(status);
       }
    });
  }
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_geocoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

really should be more like this

```
lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
```

Also you create `lat` and `lon` and then don't use them in next line.
Change this

```
addresslatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
```

to this

```
addresslatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```