# Google Javascript API call along with Geolocator code doesnt work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to see the values of latitude and longitude as global variables so that it can be used. However when the codeAddress() function is called, even before it completes execution the subsequent inside alert is printed and map is rendered blank ( Code shows hardcoded values). What am i doing wrong?

```
var geocoder;
    var geoloc;
    var latitude;
    var longitude

function codeAddress() {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = 'Dallas';
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();alert(latitude);
        longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();alert(longitude);

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following the default location set.reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
    return;
}

function getStoreMap(zoom)
{
codeAddress();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

    alert("Inside"+latitude);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.7801399,-96.80045109999998),
    zoom: zoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var panelDiv = document.getElementById('panel');
  var data = new PlacesDataSource(map);
  var view = new storeLocator.View(map, data,{ updateOnPan: true}
);

  var markerSize = new google.maps.Size(24, 24);
  view.createMarker = function(store) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: store.getLocation(),
      icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(store.getDetails().icon, null, null,
          null, markerSize)
    });
  };

  new storeLocator.Panel(panelDiv, {
    view: view
  });
});

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps API issue with geocoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606660/google-maps-api-issue-with-geocoder)

Answer (score 0):

The call to Google API is asynchronous so when you call codeAddress(), it begins the call can continues on with the rest of the code.

Then the document load is being added, and the alert is being called when the document is loaded.

The call to Google has not completed by the time the document is loading and the lat long variables are not being assigned in time.

Setup your document on load to initialize the map and make the call to geolocate. On complete function of the geolocate call, call another function will modify the map based on the results.